# Adding a row to an existing table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to add a new row in case a button is clicked. This row should be added right after the row the button is inside of. I'm using Jquery(1.10.2) to add new rows.

The problem I'm encountering is the `.closest` function doesn't work like I'm expecting it to. When I paste a hardcoded class to the `.insertAfter`, it works.

This line of code does not work for me:

```
$("<tr> <td> Test </td> </tr>").insertAfter($(this).closest('.rowToClone'));
```

As I said, when I'm hardcoding a class into the `.insertAfter()`, it does work. So I guess my problem lays in the `.closest()` function.
Edited (Whole jquery):

```
<script>

    var dagen = ["Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za", "Zo"];

    var selects = [];
    var lengte = dagen.length;

        function addRow()
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < lengte; i++)
            {
                //Get all of the hours selected by the Dropdown boxes
                selects[i] = $('select[name="' + dagen[i] + '_uurTot"] option:selected').text();

                // clone these boxes and changing the name, adding value of I from the for loop to the name Example Ma1_uurVan
                //selectVan = $('select[name="' + dagen[i] + '_uurVan"]').clone();
                //selectVan.attr("name", dagen[i] + i + "_uurVan");

                // clone these boxes and changing the name, adding value of I from the for loop to the name Example Ma1_uurTot
                //selectTot = $('select[name="' + dagen[i] + '_uurTot"]').clone();
                //selectVan.attr("name", dagen[i] + i + "_uurVan");

                // If the hours those are selected not 22:00, duplicating the row is possible.
                if(selects[i] !== '22:00')
                {
                    $("<tr> <td> Test </td> </tr>").insertAfter('.rowToClone'); // Works, but adds row to all the rows with .rowToClone
                    // $("<tr> <td> Test </td> </tr>").insertAfter($(this).closest('.rowToClone')); // DOES NOT WORK


                }
            }

        }
</script>
```

This is my html:

```
<table id="beschikbaarheid" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <input type="hidden" name="control" value="admin"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="beschikbaarheid"/>
    <thead>
        <th class="hidden-xs " style="color:white;">Dag</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs " style="color:white;">Van</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs " style="color:white;">Tot</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs " style="color:white;">Rij aanmaken</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs " style="color:white;">Status</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr class="rowToClone">
             <td>Maandag <td>
             <select name="Ma_uurVan">
                  <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
                  <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
                  <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
                  <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
                  <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                  <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
                  <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
                  <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
                  <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
                  <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
                  <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                  <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
                  <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                  <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
                  <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                  <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
                  <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
                  <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
                  <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
                  <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
                  <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
                  <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
                  <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
                  <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
                  <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
                  <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
                  <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
                  <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
                  <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
              </select>
          </td>
          <td>
              <select name="Ma_uurTot">
                  <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
                  <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
                  <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
                  <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
                  <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                  <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
                  <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
                  <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
                  <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
                  <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
                  <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                  <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
                  <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                  <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
                  <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                  <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
                  <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
                  <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
                  <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
                  <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
                  <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
                  <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
                  <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
                  <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
                  <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
                  <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
                  <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
                  <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
                  <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
              </select>
           </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" onclick="addRow()"> Voeg rij toe </button>
        </td>
        <td>
        <select name="StatusMa">
            <option>Beschikbaar</option>
            <option selected >Niet beschikbaar</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

edit: Because of the large sum of html code. I only inserted the first whole row.

Comment: `#rowToClone` selects an element with the *`id`* of `"rowToClone"`, `.rowToClone` selects elements with the *`class`* of `"rowToClone"`; and what's `lengte`?

Comment: Can you show the version of the code that *does* work?

Comment: I'm sorry I just edited the "#" part. it should be a '.' I forgot to change it when I edited it on Stackoverflow.
Scott the commented piece of code works for me, but not the uncommected. in the for loop

Comment: whithout more code context we have no idea what `this` is, or what you expect it should be. SHow more code related to button. `this` is not going to be a `<select>` in your code, use `$.each` if that's what you want `this` to be

Comment: Can you copy your code into a Stack Snippet (use the icon after the 'picture', that way we can see what's going on, and it forces you to post a complete/verifiable example...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using in your HTML:

```
<button onclick="addRow();">some text here</button>
```

try using in your js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('button').click(function(){
       selects[i] = $('select[name="' + dagen[i] + '_uurTot"] option:selected').text();

            // If the hours those are selected not 22:00, duplicating the row is possible.
            if(selects[i] !== '22:00')
            {

                $("<tr> <td> Test </td> </tr>").insertAfter($(this).closest('.rowToClone'));

            }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery function `.parent()` will get the parent of the desired item. You can work your way up to the grandparent of the button and perform a `.insertAfter()` to add a row to the table. You can see an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/2L6b9kvr/1/

In the `addRow` function I grab the grandparent element of the button (in this case it is a `tr`). I then inset the new HTML `tr` after the grandparent variable. Then I unbind and rebind all `.addRow` to the `addRow` function.